# How to use a variable within another variable - Powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-4.0

That's the prompt

```
$path= Some\Path\in\HKCU
$default = Get-Item -Path $path
$property= Get-ItemProperty -Path $path
$x = $default | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Property | Select-Object -Index 2
```

So if I try to use `$property` variable below it gives me error. How can use it here?

It works just fine if I instead write `Get-ItemProperty -Path $path` but for some reason I need it like that:

```
$value = $property -Name $x | Select-Object $x | Select-Object -expand $x
```

Comment: `& $property -Name $x | ...` <- use the `&` invocation operator

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't know why but it didn't work

Comment: You probably have to do `& $property.NameOfRegKeyValueThatContainsTheProgramToRun`

Comment: gave such an error: "The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command name, a 
script block, or a CommandInfo object."

Comment: What's the name of the value in the registry key that holds the path to the program/cmd you want to execute?

Comment: i think it is something like AudioUserSelectedRenderingEndpoint

Comment: So then `& $property.AudioUserSelectedRenderingEndpoint ...` should do

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize it. Thanks a lot!